# Calling jQuery from ASP.NET GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I found the following code in one of the old messages in StackOverflow:

```
$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr").click(function(){
    alert("Row clicked");
});
```

The code above is supposed to call an alert when user clicks in a row of a GridView.  What I don't understand, is how to define (in my GridView) what is referred in the above code as "ClientID". What is "ClientID"?

Comment: You don't need to define the ClientID. Each control has a server side ID and a ClientID. You define the server side ID and the ClientID is defined by the markup engine of asp.net. For instance <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"/> defines a TextBox control with server side ID text1. We use this ID, to access in code behind file the properties f text 1. When this control will be rendered to html, it will have a clientID, which willhave been generated by the asp.net markup engine.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your explanation.
I see the code that I copied now works.  But what if I wanted to the Alert to be called only when user clicks on a certain specific column?  
Also, please allow me to ask a general question. How do I enter a comment for two or more people who answered my question? It appears that I can Add Commnet to one and then the other. What am I missing?
Thank you again.

Comment: The ClientID property is a automatically generated identification for a control.

Answer (score 1):

This code `<%=GridView1.ClientID%>` will be run on server and will be final render as the ID of the grid view, so on the page you will final see probably this

```
$("#GridView1 tr").click(function(){
    alert("Row clicked");
});
```

The `ClientID` gives the final ID that the GridView is use on the html page.

Comment: It also depends if they use Master Pages. Then, ASP will add a `ContentPlaceHolderID` as prefix to the `GridView` ID

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk Of course, I just give an idea that is going to be render the id of.